# Configure default Language Level on IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ 14 and my machine has JDK 7 installed.
However, everytime creating new project, language level is 5.

Although i can change by going to Project Settings->Project-> Project Language Level and Project Settings->Modules->[Module Name]->Sources->Language Level, it takes time to do that for every project.

Can IntelliJ auto-detect my JDK and choose correct default Language Level or there's a default setting for Language Level?

Comment: I am new to Stackoverflow, can someone help answer why my question is voted down to -1. When I try but cannot find the answer, it's not bad to ask for help.

Comment: some people are simply like to down vote without proper reason/s and feel happy about it, just ignore these negative minds. I've upvoted as your question helped me.

Comment: It is a reasonable question. Downvotes happen. *Why*  (and sometimes *by whom* .. ) is another .. question ..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Did you check IntellJ documnentation before posting here?

Is it not this what are you searching for: 
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-global-project-and-module-sdks.html

Edit: The correct answer is File -> Other Settings -> Default Project Structure

Comment: That does only define SDKs but not the language level afaik

Comment: Ah yes, correct. I will edit my post to have the correct answer which is again in the IntelliJ documentation. Just did not had IntelliJ at that moment to check it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did look around but did not find the setting. There're tons of setting in such a big IDE and it's not easy to find one, so i dont think asking is too bad. And are you sure you can read all of the documentation to find an answer?!

Comment: I think half the point of StackOverflow is being able to find answers immediately instead of reading the documentation for 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Update from IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2 (Community Edition)

File -> New Projects Setup -> Structure

discovered this using and the "find action" option from the help menu