# Does the Community Edition built-in Java project template ignore Language Level?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, project-template

I'm using IntelliJ Idea Community 2018.1.5

I've altered the default project structure to use Language Level 10 (Using JDK 10).

When I create a new project with no additional libraries or frameworks selected and select project template (only default one available being `Command Line App`), the new project gets created with Project Structure set to use **Language Level 6**.

Is there a way for me to edit this built-in project template to either honor my default project structure language level setting or use Language Level 10 by default?

Comment: You can edit the template directly by opening IntelliJ's settings and navigating to **Editor -> File and Code Templates**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configure default Language Level on IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31621035/configure-default-language-level-on-intellij)

Comment: On the first point, the *Project Template* is not available for editing under **File and Code Templates**. That seems to be just templates for code snippets and when you create a new file, not a new project.

Comment: I've already configured the default project structure as indicated in that other answer, however when I create a new project from the built-in IntelliJ template for "Command Line App", the Language Level **does not** inherit from the default project structure language level.

Comment: @SnowInferno if it doesn't inherit, file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with the exact steps to reproduce.